# Not expected result of the query

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a query:

```sql
select * from
(
select
    p.ID
from
    MY_PRODUCT_PARENT_LINK pLink
    inner join MY_PRODUCT p on pLink.FK_PARENT=p.ID
order by
    pLink.DESCENDANT_LVL desc 
)
where rownum <= 1
;
```

The inner query returns one row with not null value of p.ID.
The outer query - one row with null value of p.ID. Here expected not null value.

The database sever is Oracle 11g.

There is a code to reproduction:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_PRODUCT
(
    FK_PARENT NUMBER(19),
    ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT PK_MY_PRODUCT PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO MY_PRODUCT (FK_PARENT, ID,NAME) VALUES (null, 111111,'PRODUCT_NAME_01');
INSERT INTO MY_PRODUCT (FK_PARENT, ID,NAME) VALUES (null, 111112,'PRODUCT_NAME_02');

CREATE TABLE MY_PRODUCT_PARENT_LINK
(
    ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    FK_PRODUCT NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    FK_PARENT NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    DESCENDANT_LVL NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    primary key (ID)
);

ALTER TABLE MY_PRODUCT_PARENT_LINK ADD
CONSTRAINT MY_PRD_PARENT_TO_MY_PRODUCT
FOREIGN KEY (FK_PRODUCT)
REFERENCES MY_PRODUCT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE MY_PRODUCT_PARENT_LINK ADD
CONSTRAINT MY_PRD_PARENT_TO_PARENT
FOREIGN KEY (FK_PARENT)
REFERENCES MY_PRODUCT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO MY_PRODUCT_PARENT_LINK (ID, FK_PRODUCT, FK_PARENT, DESCENDANT_LVL) VALUES (211111, 111112, 111111, 1);
```

Comment: Did you try changing your `WHERE` condition to `rownum = 1` or `rownum < 2` ?

Comment: This does not seem possible.  Because `p.id` is used in the `join`, it cannot have a `NULL` value.  How are you reading the values?  Could you be confusing `'NULL'` with `NULL` (that is, a string containing "NULL")?

Comment: Yes, I try to change `WHERE` condition to `rownum = 1` or `rownum < 2`, but no result. When I comment the `ORDER` statement then the query works as expected.

Comment: If you want us to diagnose a mysterious query result you need to post a small sample of the raw data so we can attempt to reproduce your situation.  You won't get a decent answer until you do this.

Comment: I added the sample. If replace `inner join` to `left join` then result is ok.

Comment: When comment `where rownum <= 1` statement then value of `p.ID` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try and select the ID in the outer query and see if that returns the result. so instead of select * in the outer do select ID.